# How can I call a stored procedure that is using a cursor in C#?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

How can I call a stored procedure like the one shown below with a cursor, using C#?

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Customers_Cursor1]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- DECLARE THE VARIABLES FOR HOLDING DATA.
    DECLARE @CustomerId INT,
            @Name VARCHAR(100),
            @Country VARCHAR(100)
 
    -- DECLARE AND SET COUNTER.
    DECLARE @Counter INT
    SET @Counter = 1
 
    -- DECLARE THE CURSOR FOR A QUERY.
    DECLARE PrintCustomers CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
        SELECT CustomerId, Name, Country
        FROM Customers
 
    -- OPEN CURSOR.
    OPEN PrintCustomers
 
    -- FETCH THE RECORD INTO THE VARIABLES.
    FETCH NEXT FROM PrintCustomers INTO @CustomerId, @Name, @Country
 
    -- LOOP UNTIL RECORDS ARE AVAILABLE.
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @CustomerId, @Name, @Country

        -- FETCH THE NEXT RECORD INTO THE VARIABLES.
        FETCH NEXT FROM PrintCustomers INTO @CustomerId, @Name, @Country
    END
 
    -- CLOSE THE CURSOR.
    CLOSE PrintCustomers
    DEALLOCATE PrintCustomers
END
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your procedure does not need to use a `CURSOR` _at all_. Why are you using a cursor instead of a straightforward set-based query? Set-based queries are much faster and efficient compared to cursors...

Comment: Also, `varchar(100)` is an inappropriate type for human-readable text (`@name` and `@country`), why aren't you using `nvarchar` for those?

Comment: This entire procedure could be boiled down to just `SELECT CustomerId, Name, Country FROM Customers` the cursor is absolutely not necessary, is horribly slow, and a pain to deal with from the C# side

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

In SQL

```
Exec Customers_Cursor1 <CustomerID>, <Name>, <Country>
```

In C#:

```
using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
            {
            SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("Customers_Cursor1", Connection);
            Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Command.CommandTimeout = CommandTimeout;
         
                Command.Connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                DataTable MyTable = new DataTable(); //Returns a Table from the Query
                MyTable.Load(dr);
                dr.Close();

               return MyTable;
            }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Error "'Procedure PrintCustomers_Cursor1 has no parameters and arguments were supplied.'"

Comment: Updated c# code, removed the parameters.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: `dr` needs a `using` block